# Ionic Framework - Google Maps in Android not working after publishing on Play Store

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, webview, ionic-framework

I have made a fully functioning Ionic app which includes some templates with an embed Google Maps on them. Those are working flawlessly when I'm running the development server and even when I generate an apk and install it directly to my device, but once I publish it to the Play Store, they just don't show up. Geolocation doesn't seem to be an issue since there are some maps that make use of it and some that not, but neither of them work.

I believe the problem to be permission related, and I was hoping you could give me some directions on what is wrong with the configuration, or other issues that may have caused the problem in your experience. Below I paste my config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml files.

Thank you in advance!

config.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.cpnl642617" version="0.0.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Jocs en català</name>
  <description>&#xD;
        App per promoure jocs i joguines en català.&#xD;
    </description>
  <author email="jvilarnau@cpnl.cat" href="http://cpnl.cat">&#xD;
      CPNL&#xD;
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="5" android:versionName="0.0.5" package="com.ionicframework.cpnl642617" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```